# ArgumentError: is not a recognized provider rake rails posgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, carrierwave

I'm trying to clone and setup a rails repo.

when I run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` I get the following error with no user name:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError:  is not a recognized providerronment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be a problem with the provider. If I were you, I would try to set up the provider again.

```
provider:               ENV['FOG_PROVIDER']
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to ruby, rails and postgresql. How would I go about setting it up?

Comment: @Sujio I would try with 'AWS' again, have a look at the documentation on GitHub. https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3